# Rails: Ajax for Like button when iterating through status updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Users index action I am iterating through all the Users who have posted a status update and ordering them by created_at DESC.

In my index.html.view

```
<% @users.each.do |user| %>
<% user.status = @status %>
<%= @status.content %>

<div id ="like_form">
    <% if @status.has_like_already?(@status, current_user)%>
        <%= render 'already_liked'%>
    <%else%>
    <%= render 'like'%>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

_like.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Like", likes_path(:like_for => @status.id), remote: true, :method=>:post %>
```

_already_liked.html.erb

```
<span>Liked</span>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#like_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/already_liked')) %>")
```

The issue is that I am able to like a status update and for the first post  the Like button changes to Unlike, but on subsequent clicks the like button doesn't change to Unlike. This is because `#like_form` for the first post has already been changed to Unlike. Since I am iterating, how do I get the like functionality to work with Ajax for each status posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add user id to div, so you can unique your div's id.

index.html.erb

```
<div id ="like_form_<%= user.id %>">

</div>
```

_like.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Like", likes_path(:like_for => @status.id, :user_id=>user.id), remote: true, :method=>:post %>
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#like_form_<%= params[:user_id]%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unlike')) %>")
```